# how to install flac support (flac libraries) to sox in Windows

Tags: speech-recognition, voice-recognition, sox, flac, libsox

when I try to work on flac files I got

"no handler for file extension flac"

error. is there any way to solve this problem in windows.

Comment: plz check `sox --help` and the `flac` is included in `AUDIO FILE FORMATS`. BTW, "SoX can read native FLAC files (.flac) but not Ogg FLAC files (.ogg)".

Comment: I have complated 86 pages of sox help file. I think because it is originally written for linux it is not easy to understand it

Comment: The second thing, some other says I need to compile sox.exe with flac support (it is linux process not windows) and I have no idea what to do...

Answer (score 9):

This answer may be a bit late, but you want version 14.4.1a (available [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sox/files/sox/14.4.1/sox-14.4.1a-win32.exe/download)). FLAC was disabled accidentally in 14.4.1 which is still the default on SourceForge.